Solve $2x^4+4x^2+1=0$ and find all real solutions.

Solve $2x^4+4x^2+1=0$ and find all real solutions.

Let $x^2=w$
$2w^2+4w+1=0$
By the quadratic equation:
$w=x^2=\dfrac{-4 \pm\sqrt{4^2-8}}{4}=\dfrac{-2\pm\sqrt{2}}{2}$
$x=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{-2\pm\sqrt{2}}{2}}=\pm\dfrac{-2\sqrt{2}\pm2}{2}=\pm(-\sqrt{2}\pm2)$
$x_1=-\sqrt{2}+2 \\ x_2=\sqrt{2}-2 \\ x_3=-\sqrt{2}-2 \\ x_4=\sqrt{2}+2$
All four solutions are real. But the answer is given as no real solution exists. I think that's a typo. Or am I wrong?

None of the four roots you listed satisfy the original equation.

$-2 + \sqrt{2}$ is negative and so is $-2 - \sqrt{2}$ so you can't take square root of them

Apart from that something went wrong when you were taking this square root (it somehow disappeared and there was some multiplication by $2$ in a numerator)

Everything up to here looks fine:

$w = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{2}}{2}$

Note that because $\sqrt{2} < 2$, then both solutions for $w$ are negative. Since you defined $x^2 = w$, this shows that there are no real solutions for $x$.

The quartic $2x^4+4x^2+1$ is always positive for real $x$ as $x^4$ and $x^2$ are always non-negative, so the equation has no real roots.

This very simple observation is useful for many problems, not just here, when there are only $+$ signs in a polynomial this should raise eyebrows.

Notice that both of the values of $w$ are negative so $x^2 = w$ has no real solution. In other words, the quartic factors into a pair of quadratics over the real numbers, but no further:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2x^4 + 4x^2 + 1 
&= 2 \biggl( x^2 - \Bigl(-1 + \tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \Bigr) \biggr) 
\biggl( x^2 - \Bigl(-1 - \tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \Bigr) \biggr) \\
&= 2 \biggl( x^2 + \underbrace{1 - \tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}_{\geq 0} \biggr) 
\biggl( x^2 + \underbrace{1 + \tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}_{\geq 0} \biggr) 
\end{aligned}
$$
